# Event registration confirmation mail: Can I suppress certain custom fields?

Tags: civievent

For my event, I set up a number of custom fields for the participants. One of these is sensitive, and I would like to avoid sending it via email.

Any idea, how this can be achieved?

Cheers,
Detlev

Answer (score 2):

Administer -> Communications -> Message Templates -> system Workflow Messages

Where you can find all the message template for all Emails so find the Event registration template (Events - Registration Confirmation and Receipt (on-line / off-line))

and remove your custom field which you don't want to send

Comment: But why are custom fields there by default. It includes them from contributions and there is no obvious reason for wanting to share those with the participant.